# Build a prefix operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Suppose I have this class:

```
class Int{
    private:
        int x;
    public:
        Int(int i) : x(i) {}
};
```

Can I build a `prefix +` operator to write expression such `x = + a b`?

I tried to overload `operator+` inside the class but the compiler complain that  `operator+` must be unary or binary and not ternary.

Is there a way to do such thing?

Comment: What do you want `= +` to mean?  As written, this is algebraic nonsense.

Comment: No, there's no way to start writing Lisp in C++ (even though we may want to). (Coincidentally, `x = + a` will work but not `x = + a b`.)

Comment: @JohnDibling: He's describing [Prefix Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation).

Comment: @RobertHarvey:  Ah, should have known.  I have an HP50g calculator sitting 3 inches from me. :)

Comment: @JohnDibling: Being pedantic, HP calculators are *postfix* notation (a b +), versus *prefix* notation (+ a b).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the way that the '+' character is interpreted by the compiler - it has special syntactic significance. If you're willing to give up the + symbol, though, you could create a class called `plus` and overload operator() to take its following arguments.

Essentially, you're creating a dsl using the `plus` class as a proxy for the + operator.

Comment: Oh, maybe I got. So it is impossible because of the parser? If you write `+ x x` there is not any syntatic rule that match. Is it (more or less) right?

Answer (score 4):

No you can't change the basic syntax of the expression.

Answer (score 3):

In general it is not possible to fiddle with the basic syntax of C++, because it is hardwired into the grammar. But maybe

```
template<typename A, typename B>
auto plus(const A& a, const B& b) -> decltype(a + b) { return a + b; }
a = plus(a, b);
```

is a suitable replacement? Building this for all arithmetic operators is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Expr {
  int value;
  enum oper { plus = '+', minus = '-', times = '*', div = '/', nop = 0 } op;
  Expr(int value, oper op) : value(value), op(op) { }
  Expr(int value) : value(value), op(nop) {}
  Expr operator+() { return Expr(value, plus); }
  Expr operator-() { return Expr(value, minus); }
  Expr operator*() { return Expr(value, times); }
  Expr operator,(const Expr& rhs) {
    Expr result(value, op);
    switch(op) {
      case '+': result.value += rhs.value; break;
      case '-': result.value -= rhs.value; break;
      case '*': result.value *= rhs.value; break;
      case '/': result.value /= rhs.value; break;
    }
    return result;
  }
};

int main () {
  Expr x(0), a(1), b(2);
  x = ( + a , b );
  std::cout << x.value << "\n";
}
```